# GSA not following links

Tags: google-search-appliance

We have multiple sites indexed in our GSA. For site abc.com, everything works perfectly. The start URL is the home page, and links from there are followed properly by GSA and the entire site is indexed.

For site def.com, the setup is the same (start URL, follow patterns) and the links are valid. The home page gets indexed but the links from there are not followed. But if I index a linked page directly by recrawling it, it gets added. License limit is not the issue - the number of crawled documents is well below the limit. I have also made sure the pages are not skipped due to "do not follow patterns". The site does not have a robots.txt file, so no exclusions there either. There are no noindex/nofollow/googleon/googleoff tags.

So why is GSA unable to follow links?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how def.com renders the content. If the links are built in run time for the site def.com at the browser end, GSA would not be able to replicate it to understand the links on the page.

Comment: It is not built in runtime. If I submit the page for a manual recrawl, and view cached copy of the page, the links are present statically.

Comment: Is the def.com something available for lookup? Are you able to view the real time index and crawl activity for def.com when you fetch manually? You can setup def.com/ as url pattern to capture and manually fetch to see how GSA crawls and what happens to the url found.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the def.com home page on your browser and look for anchor tags.`<a href= />`.
If it is present obviously GSA will follow the urls and index the same.
You can also check the crawl diagnostics ([Number of links on this page to crawled pages](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/admin_console_help/status_crawl_diagnostics.html)) of the def.com home page to know whether GSA is able to discover links from your home page.

If GSA is not discovering links from the home page then go ahead and create jump page for def.com website and index that with noindex robots meta tag.

Hope it helps.